# Linq & unsupported data types (Geography)

Tags: linq-to-sql, geography, spatial-query

So, Linq does not support the `Geography` data type, which throws a major spanner in the works in the lovely 'drag table onto the Linq design surface' developemnt model.

Is there any way that I can extend Linq to work with the Geography datatype?
Or will I need to build a whole new datalayer and set of queries for whenever I need to use Geography columns?

I've been stuck on this for a few days and can't work out if it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

Cast the column to a varbinary(max), which Linq to SQL *can* handle.  One way to avoid doing this in every query is just to add a computed column defined as `CAST(GeographyColumn AS varbinary(max))`.

Once you have the `byte[]` data, you can write a short utility method to convert it to the actual `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography` class using a `MemoryStream` and the `IBinarySerialize`.`Read`/`Write` methods.

As far as I know, this is the only working solution if you need to work with any CLR type, including geography, geometry, hierarchyid, and any custom types - Linq doesn't "natively" support any of them.  It's a bit of a pain to write all the boilerplate code, but you can make it easier with a few extension methods.

You won't be able to query against the column this way; however, you can get what I would call halfway there using the [Linq Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).  You won't have intellisense or some of the other Linq goodies, but it's still composable and therefore better than hand-crafting every query, and you can get strong-typed results.

Update: I found a slightly cleaner solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/b0ac34d7-91de-4af9-8064-af4625fd6a25/).  You can use the designer this way; just add the `SqlGeography` wrapper property to a partial class and use the `STGeomFromWKB` method with the `SqlBytes` class.  That still won't give you inline query capabilities, though.

Comment: Ok, but that won't do anything to help me run spatial queries will it? I mean, I would still have to create my own queries if I wanted to 
do the likes of `SELECT X WHERE Y.STIntersects(X)`

Comment: Yes, you will, unfortunately - even if there were a better way to coax Linq to SQL into accepting the CLR type as a column, it still wouldn't know how to map its methods into SQL function calls.  Your best bet is to write these queries as SPs or UDFs in SQL Server itself, but if you absolutely must write your SQL within the app, then you might be able to get what you want using the Linq Dynamic Query Library.

Comment: I updated the reply with a link in case you're not familiar with DynamicQuery.

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlspatial/thread/df1dc078-0b96-4209-8032-e32d9ba81294) you'll have to manually map/parse it yourself to your own POCO type.