# Use Geography-column with LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

I recently ran into the problem that i can't work with a table that has a Geography-column in the Visual Studio data designer. So is there any way to get this to work? Does MVC4 support it? Or do i need to run the latest VS beta?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq & unsupported data types (Geography)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892381/linq-unsupported-data-types-geography)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework 5 will natively support geography types.

See the [CTP announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx), and the [EF5 beta 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/29/ef4-3-1-and-ef5-beta-1-available-on-nuget.aspx) announcement.

You will also need VS11 beta and .NET 4.5.